# Flutter: Scraping a site with JavaScript generated content without dart:html

Tags: dart, flutter

How do I scrape a web page that generates some of its content with a JavaScript element? It is a local court booking site for my squash club and from what I can see, this is the JavaScript script it calls to retrieve the court bookings:

```
function load_js(url) {
    var e = document.createElement("script");
    e.src = url;
    e.type = "text/javascript";
    if (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].lastChild.src == e.src) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].replaceChild(e, document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].lastChild);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
    }
}

onload = function () {
    setInterval("load_js('/js/bookings_reload.js.php')", 30000);
};
```

How could I replicate this in Flutter? I can scrape the HTML and parse it to create an HTML document, but since Flutter disallows the use of the dart:html library, I can't create a ScriptElement to duplicate the JavaScript script. Is there an alternative in Flutter?

Here is my Dart function so far:

```
var httpClient = createHttpClient();
getData() async {
      // Send POST request to get authorized cookie
      var response = await httpClient.post('http://bookings.squashgym.co.nz/login',
          body: {'username': username, 'password': password});

      // Send get request with authenticated cookie to get bookings
      var courts = await httpClient.get('http://bookings.squashgym.co.nz/booking-sheet',
      headers: {'cookie': response.headers['set-cookie']});

      Document data = parse(courts.body);
      httpClient.close();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You may have better luck using a WebView. I don't have the code for this, so I can't leave an answer, but you may be able to open an "invisible" webview, ask it to load the URL, wait until you're satisfied that the page rendered, and then get the DOM from the WebView.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http you can import http?

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Answer (score 1):

I agree on using WebView to load the URL needed. Here is an example implementation of WebView using the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev/",
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how it will look like:

[image]

And when the page is rendered you will be able to get the DOM from the WebView. There is also an available example of getting DOM from WebView. Check it [here](https://gist.github.com/fredriccliver/97f98965d765107086ea045ee7c7909b).